# Limit the number of characters in a textarea

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I would like to prevent the seizure of more than 100 characters in a `textarea` using **jquery-validation-engine**.

It works for input, but not for a `textarea`.

```
<textarea class="validate[maxSize[100]] Pt_Textarea" type="text" name="descriptif" id="descriptif" data-prompt-position="topLeft" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid `textarea` needs a closing tag `<textarea>Content</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="15" maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

Using a script taken from [Textarea maxlength with Jquery](http://that-matt.com/2008/07/textarea-maxlength-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `type="textarea"` instead of `type="text"`.